# Popup iframe not moving when resizing the page

Tags: javascript, css, iframe

I have an iframe element that, when I click on a picture, it will open below it.

My problem is that, when I open the popup (iframe) and resize the page, the iframe is not keeping the position below the picture.

```
iframeLoginControl.style.position = 'absolute';
iframeLoginControl.style.left = parseInt(imgBtnPos.left) - 12 + "px";
iframeLoginControl.style.top = parseInt(imgBtnPos.top) + parseInt(imgButtonObj.height) - 1 + "px";
```

I think my problem is with `imgBtnPos.left` that not gets refreshed when I resize the page.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that you're positioning the `iframe` absolutely, and outside the *natural* flow of the page. Your coordinate is referenced to the top left of the relative parent the moment you set it.

You have to position the `iframe` relative to the `image` - that way it will move with the page's flow.

You haven't supplied the way you attach the iframe to the document, but if you attach it inline, and you don't position it absolutely, it should work fine.

Comment: ok thank i success be creating a id proprety to the iframe iframeLoginControl["MyAncoreElementID"] = imgButtonObj.id;

Comment: Not sure my answer helped, but I'm glad you found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should detail this with a bit more code.
First of all, you have to recalculate the position in the "onresize" event of your window element. If you're already doing that, check the 'imgBtnPos' variable in your code: what is it? is it a reference to your DOM element? if so, you have forgot to put '.style' keyword before '.left' and '.top'